# jQuery datepicker issue with IE8 in Client Citrix Environment

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datepicker, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently developing a web application using standard asp.net (no MVC) for a client where a text box is required to have a calendar-datepicker and should not be having user input enabled.

I have used the following references by downloading the corresponding files:

```
<script src="myScripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="myScripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="myScripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

the text field where I am adding the datepicker is as below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRequestDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

The javascript code used for the textbox is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtRequestDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'd/m/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

It has worked fine in my local system where I am using VS 2015 and IE11/Chrome for testing.

However, development for client is being done in a Citrix environment where I have VS2013 and IE8 for use.

There were compatibility issues faced with IE8 for jQuery-3.2.1, which on reading the internet, i changed by jQuery version to :

```
<script src="myScripts/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
```

In my local system, I changed the IE11 emulation mode to IE8 via F12 Developer Tools and it worked.

However, in the Citrix system, there is no result coming up. On clicking the textbox nothing happens. I'm not getting any error message popping up as well.

Any advice on how this can be rectified.

Thanks in Advance.